# DB2 DROP AND CREATE TABLE

Tags: db2, sql-pl

I'm trying to ensure when i run a stored procedure it checks if a table exists and if it does it drops it then re-creates the table. Using the following stored proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
if( exists(
select 1 from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'AELUM' and tabname = 'ROOTNODES'
)) then

drop table AELUM.ROOTNODES ;

CREATE TABLE "AELUM"."ROOTNODES" (
"UID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER ),
"NODENAME" VARCHAR(255),
"HASCHILD" INTEGER,
"CHILDTABLE" VARCHAR(255)
)
DATA CAPTURE NONE;

**-->>ALTER TABLE "AELUM"."ROOTNODES" ADD CONSTRAINT "ROOTNODES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("UID");

end if;

END P1
```

Now the point labeled above **-->> isn't liked by data studio. I am not sure what is wrong with this statement. please help

Comment: Why not create the PK as part of the CREATE TABLE?

Comment: Have you set the statement separator to something other than the semicolon? Semicolons have a different meaning in stored procedures and the default of also having them as a statement separator is ambiguous. It's defined by Right-click -> Set Statement Separator. I usually use @ when dealing with stored procs.

Comment: Thank you. That works, I it the procedure as follows 
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
if( exists(
select * from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'AELUM' and tabname = 'ROOTNODES'
)) then

drop table AELUM.ROOTNODES ;

CREATE TABLE "AELUM"."ROOTNODES" (
"UID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER ) PRIMARY KEY,
"NODENAME" VARCHAR(255),
"HASCHILD" INTEGER,
"CHILDTABLE" VARCHAR(255)
)
DATA CAPTURE NONE;



end if;
END P1

I shall try changing the statement separator

Comment: Can anyone tell me how I can use the ALTER statement in a db2 stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DB2, but in Oracle you cannot perform DDL in standard PL/SQL. Instead, you have to put the DDL as a `VARCHAR2` and perform an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table AELUM.ROOTNODES';
```